# Materializecss multiple select no firing change in Angular 2

Tags: angular, materialize

Using `materializecss` "multiple select" does not appear to fire `change`. How can you bind a method for when the select changes.

The following code does not fire change.

```
HTML
<select id="booger" multiple>
    <option value="1">{{articleIdLabel}}</option>
    <option value="2">{{articlePubDateLabel}}</option>
    <option value="3">{{articleTitleLabel}}</option>
    <option value="4">{{articleViewDateLabel}}</option>
</select>
```

---

```
Component
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $("#booger").material_select();
}

change() {
    console.log("change");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem with the following change to my code:

```
Component
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $("#booger").material_select(this.change.bind(this));
}

change() {
    console.log("change");
}
```

Comment: Hey, @prolink007 I was able to get this working on my projects, Thanks a lot!. I am stuck in a case where I need to get the value of the currently selected option. How would I proceed to do that, any pointer would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Its working for me

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select formControlName="status" [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus" materialize="material_select">
        <option [ngValue]="" disabled>Select</option>
        <option [ngValue]="1">Enable</option>
        <option [ngValue]="0">Disable</option>
    </select>
    <label>Status</label>
</div>
```